svg auto-scaling with fixed canvas size between end-user resolutions
I have a Power BI which I'm using the HTML Content visual to generate a .svg image.  By default, the canvas is 1280x720 for maximum compatibility (this I cannot change).  The .svg was created in Canva, using the 1920x1080 resolution (because of how PBI scales background images it provided the best of both worlds between 720/2K users).  Now I want to make my .svg dynamic, which requires the URL/code itself vs .svg file I previously used.  The most common resolution for end-users is 720P and 1080P, followed by 2K resolution.  When using the "Canvas Background" with the .svg file (Fit), everything appears fine for all resolutions despite some quality falloff as a result of the magnification/scaling.  However, when I use the HTML Content visual code below, there is a scrollbar vertically or it simply doesn't fit right.
Does anyone know how I can adapt the .svg code to auto-resize properly with the 720 Power BI canvas, while maintaining optimal quality in 720/1080/2K resolutions?
 <div id="htmlContent">
   <div class="htmlViewerEntry">
     <div><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1920" zoomAndPan="magnify" viewBox="0 0 1440 809.999993" height="1080" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" version="1.0">
         <defs>
           <clipPath id="ccc1313c42">
             <path d="M 9 321.75 L 1431 321.75 L 1431 801 L 9 801 Z M 9 321.75 " clip-rule="nonzero"></path>
           </clipPath>
           <clipPath id="31f810a456">
             <path d="M 15 321.75 L 1425 321.75 C 1426.589844 321.75 1428.117188 322.382812 1429.242188 323.507812 C 1430.367188 324.632812 1431 326.160156 1431 327.75 L 1431 795 C 1431 796.589844 1430.367188 798.117188 1429.242188 799.242188 C 1428.117188 800.367188 1426.589844 801 1425 801 L 15 801 C 13.410156 801 11.882812 800.367188 10.757812 799.242188 C 9.632812 798.117188 9 796.589844 9 795 L 9 327.75 C 9 326.160156 9.632812 324.632812 10.757812 323.507812 C 11.882812 322.382812 13.410156 321.75 15 321.75 Z M 15 321.75 " clip-rule="nonzero"></path>
           </clipPath>
           <clipPath id="bc7ff15eda">
             <path d="M 9 72 L 1431 72 L 1431 315 L 9 315 Z M 9 72 " clip-rule="nonzero"></path>
           </clipPath>
           <clipPath id="f0e6ad0f51">
             <path d="M 15 72 L 1425 72 C 1426.589844 72 1428.117188 72.632812 1429.242188 73.757812 C 1430.367188 74.882812 1431 76.410156 1431 78 L 1431 309 C 1431 310.589844 1430.367188 312.117188 1429.242188 313.242188 C 1428.117188 314.367188 1426.589844 315 1425 315 L 15 315 C 13.410156 315 11.882812 314.367188 10.757812 313.242188 C 9.632812 312.117188 9 310.589844 9 309 L 9 78 C 9 76.410156 9.632812 74.882812 10.757812 73.757812 C 11.882812 72.632812 13.410156 72 15 72 Z M 15 72 " clip-rule="nonzero"></path>
           </clipPath>
           <clipPath id="580c759edc">
             <path d="M 0 0 L 1440 0 L 1440 59.625 L 0 59.625 Z M 0 0 " clip-rule="nonzero"></path>
           </clipPath>
         </defs>
         <path fill="#444141" d="M 0 0 L 1439.648438 0 L 1439.648438 810 L 0 810 Z M 0 0 " fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
         <g clip-path="url(#ccc1313c42)">
           <g clip-path="url(#31f810a456)">
             <path fill="#333333" d="M 9 321.75 L 1431.773438 321.75 L 1431.773438 801 L 9 801 Z M 9 321.75 " fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
             <path stroke-linecap="butt" transform="matrix(0.75, 0, 0, 0.75, 9.000006, 321.750004)" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="miter" d="M 7.999993 -0.00000508426 L 1888.000087 -0.00000508426 C 1890.119879 -0.00000508426 1892.156337 0.843745 1893.656338 2.343745 C 1895.156338 3.843745 1896.000088 5.880204 1896.000088 7.999995 L 1896.000088 631.000027 C 1896.000088 633.119818 1895.156338 635.156277 1893.656338 636.656277 C 1892.156337 638.156277 1890.119879 639.000027 1888.000087 639.000027 L 7.999993 639.000027 C 5.880201 639.000027 3.843743 638.156277 2.343742 636.656277 C 0.843742 635.156277 -0.00000769259 633.119818 -0.00000769259 631.000027 L -0.00000769259 7.999995 C -0.00000769259 5.880204 0.843742 3.843745 2.343742 2.343745 C 3.843743 0.843745 5.880201 -0.00000508426 7.999993 -0.00000508426 Z M 7.999993 -0.00000508426 " stroke="#666262" stroke-width="4" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-miterlimit="4"></path>
           </g>
         </g>
         <g clip-path="url(#bc7ff15eda)">
           <g clip-path="url(#f0e6ad0f51)">
             <path fill="#333333" d="M 9 72 L 1430.929688 72 L 1430.929688 315 L 9 315 Z M 9 72 " fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
             <path stroke-linecap="butt" transform="matrix(0.75, 0, 0, 0.75, 9.000006, 72.000016)" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="miter" d="M 7.999993 -0.000021837 L 1888.000087 -0.000021837 C 1890.119879 -0.000021837 1892.156337 0.843728 1893.656338 2.343728 C 1895.156338 3.843728 1896.000088 5.880187 1896.000088 7.999979 L 1896.000088 315.999994 C 1896.000088 318.119786 1895.156338 320.156244 1893.656338 321.656244 C 1892.156337 323.156244 1890.119879 323.999994 1888.000087 323.999994 L 7.999993 323.999994 C 5.880201 323.999994 3.843743 323.156244 2.343742 321.656244 C 0.843742 320.156244 -0.00000769259 318.119786 -0.00000769259 315.999994 L -0.00000769259 7.999979 C -0.00000769259 5.880187 0.843742 3.843728 2.343742 2.343728 C 3.843743 0.843728 5.880201 -0.000021837 7.999993 -0.000021837 Z M 7.999993 -0.000021837 " stroke="#666262" stroke-width="4" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-miterlimit="4"></path>
           </g>
         </g>
         <g clip-path="url(#580c759edc)">
           <path fill="#303030" d="M 0 0 L 1440.082031 0 L 1440.082031 59.625 L 0 59.625 Z M 0 0 " fill-opacity="1" fill-rule="nonzero"></path>
         </g>
         <path stroke-linecap="butt" transform="matrix(1.125, 0, 0, 1.125, 0.00000622222, 59.625017)" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="miter" d="M -0.00000553086 0.999985 L 1280.000059 0.999985 " stroke="#e20074" stroke-width="2" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-miterlimit="4"></path>
       </svg></div>
   </div>
 </div>

Thank you

The issue is not the scroll bar.  You have to change the resolution.  You are just cropping the image.  If you do not want to change resolution than you have to get the center of the image or change the scaling.

There's no way to auto scale? When I remove width and height then it scales but the scrollbars is still there

Read following : https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Remove-Horizontal-Scroll-Bars/m-p/18783

What does a chart visual with a scrollbar in PBI have to do with a HTML Content visual? These are two completely different visuals, one of which is specific to SVG content. I'm not using a chart so categorical/continuous is not applicable in any capacity.

You have a html webpage with multiple views.  Each view can have a scrollbar.  A chart is a view and your SVG is a view.  You want to auto scale a view.

I was able to solve this problem. For some reason, this is a known issue with the HTML Content visual in Power BI (specifically HTML Viewer content), as it natively adds padding to the bottom of the code.  I solved this by adding the following to the top of my code in my original question.
 <style id="visualUserStylesheet" name="visualUserStylesheet" type="text/css">
  div {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .os-scrollbar {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>

While not ideal and it theoretically doesn't remove that padding, it works by removing the scrollbars in addition to remove the ability to scroll with the mouse wheel or keyboard arrows.
